# Should I ask multiple near-duplicate questions per distributor/brand?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I asked [What are the manufacturer codes for rebranded lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103594)

My intent when writing the question is that people with knowledge of different distributors and brands could write new answers, similar to [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496). However, it's been suggested that the question is too broad and should focus on just one distributor or brand (Vivitar).

Should there be a single question for this topic or multiple, near-duplicate questions for each distributor/brand?

Comment: Another option is to fold it into [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496) since the serial number in which manufacturer identity is encoded is a "cryptic number".

Comment: Someone voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based". :-/ This is _meta_ — the point of which is to help settle the site's collective opinions.

Comment: All of meta can be closed now.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the other options are really right. Instead, ask a single question about the actual problem you are having. This site is not a good place for exhaustive lists.

The question [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496) is proof that this is a problem — it was a horrible mess until scottbb took a significant amount of time and broke it into per-brand answers, and even then it's still not pretty.

Comment: The "actual" problem is there are a whole bunch of lenses for which I want to identify the manufacturer. They are branded by distributors who are known to have encoded the actual manufacturer in the serial number, such as Vivitar, Sears, K-Mart, JCPenney, and others. If I ask "How do I identify the manufacturer?" I technically already know the answer – it is encoded in the serial number, and I need to find a manufacturer list somewhere.

Comment: But do you literally actually have those lenses (not "actually" in quotes), or do you just want there to exist a list?

Comment: The issue is if I ask how to identify a lens without specifying that I know the manufacturer is encoded on the product, someone will write that as the answer, which is useless info (that I already know) b/c the manufacturer can't be identified without the list.  I could write Qs for specific lenses, but that significantly limits the usefulness of the answers to anyone else b/c the distributors used multiple manufacturers.

Comment: @xiota I'm with Matt on this one. There's nothing _inherently_ wrong about the questions you're asking. It's just that they're several copy/paste questions that are essentially a string replacement template of each other (i.e., `s/Vivitar/Sears/`, etc.). That's a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that perhaps you're applying the wrong tool (Stack Exchange) to the problem of cataloging what you want. It has all the hallmarks of asking for list-style information or answers, much like a wiki. In fact, the primary resource for the Vivitar answer is a MediaWiki-powered wiki.

Comment: The point of the "lens number and letter codes" question is that it was in response to **frequent** questions (and ancillary questions during discussions) here, so that the site wouldn't get cluttered answering the same trivial information over and over. As a list-type question, it certainly doesn't fit the normal Stack Exchange pattern well. However, **it is the exception that proves the rule**.

Comment: @scottbb What you describe is the aftermath.  There was originally a single Q that got flagged as "too broad" and mattdm's suggestion was to limit to just Vivitar, which necessitated the creation of the other Qs to cover the lenses I want to identify the manufacturer of.

Comment: @xiota And my point is that, _on the whole_, it has all the appearances of applying the wrong tool to solve the problem. I don't see a need to examine each step along the way or subdivide or atomize the issues. From 40,000 feet, it just has a code smell, is all.